# Jython error: java.util.zip.DataFormatException: invalid code lengths set

Tags: python-requests, jython

Using StreamSets Jython (Python 2.7) processor when I make an API call using Python requests module

```
r = requests.get("https://someurl.com", headers={"Authorization":"Bearer sometokenstring"})
```

I get an error:

```
INFO java.util.zip.DataFormatException: invalid code lengths set.
```

Same code runs without this error in a linux terminal with Python 2.7. Any ideas to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

This got resolved by adding a requests header attribute: "Accept-Encoding": "deflate" as the zip format data was causing some issue. So now the request looks like:

```
r = requests.get("https://someurl.com", headers={"Authorization":"Bearer sometokenstring","Accept-Encoding":"deflate"})
```